# Circle-based 2D platformer collision

Tags: c#, collision-detection

So, I'm trying to make a 2D platformer where the level is circle-shaped, and I have trouble to get the collision detection working. It's mostly the collision detection to the sides of the tiles that doesn't work..

I've tried various ways (mostly point-based collision checks), but the player alsways glitched around or got stuck in the floor.

More detail about my game structure:

The level is tilebased. A tile is a certain amount of degrees wide and a certain amount of radius high.

The player is a square. "Horizontal" movement is handled via rotating the player around the center of the level, and vertical movement is just movement on the axis between the player and the center of the level.

Here is an example:
https://twitter.com/Xera_Nox/status/368742995803131904/photo/1

I'm building this in Unity with the Futile 2D framework.

Comment: " A tile is a certain amount of degrees wide and a certain amount of radius high."  ..... HUH?

Comment: Grepping for things with "hit", I noticed this interesting method:  `FButton.HandleSingleTouchBegan`, could this be what you're looking for?  But that is only checking against a `Rect`, hence your question which involves more interesting geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, a bit reminiscent of Tempest ;-)